How to capture PointerPressed event within whole user control rather than just on the elements inside? Windows App
I have a UserControl that i wish to capture the PointerPressed event on.
Simply capturing the event on the user control itself like so:
<UserControl
    ...
    PointerPressed="UserControl_PointerPressed"
>

only invokes the event on mouse clicks on elements inside the control.
The control is outlined by a border, which i wish the event to be invoked when a click is made inside, but on most of the empty space within the border the event doesn't occur.
Is there a way of doing this?

Setting the background of the border in question to transparent did the trick
